# Bootstrap tour not scrolling in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-tour

I’m having trouble getting my Bootstrap Tour to position properly in IE11. It works as expected in Chrome, Firefox, & Safari. If steps are below the visible area, the page tries to display but does not scroll. If the window is resized or the debugger is opened, the tour adjusts and displays as initially expected.

The page includes references to...
jQuery 1.8.2 (Dated version required for other features. Testing with 2.1.3 did not correct the tour issue.)
jQueryUI 1.10.2
Bootstrap 3.2.0
Bootstrap Tour 0.10.1

StackOverflow won't let me add images because my reputation is so low and public access is not allowed on the site. Here is a link to my post in the Bootstrap Tour GitHub that contains screen shots.

https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/377

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by an IE compatibility tag setting the level to IE9.